# Viewport display is missing in material properties

Tags: materials, color

Sometimes when I join objects I lose the capability of change the color using the viewport display.

This is the example when it works on the right way:
[image]

But suddenly after joining objects I lose other properties like "Viewport display, settings..." like this:
[image]

How can I return from the second image to the first image?
Why is this happening?

My bad solution is to right click on the material object and choose "Unlink" but I have to do this in all the objects with the same material.

Comment: Is this Blender 2.83.5? 2.90? 2.91?

Comment: Is blender 2.83

Comment: There are several different versions of 2.83, I haven't upgraded past 2.83.4. There are a few people here that seem to be having  issues with 2.83.5. Which version of 2.83 are you using?